# CSV file how to break lines?

Tags: c++, csv

I've been struggling with parsing a csv file so that every new line is read as a new row. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer in the SO forums that addressed my problem. I opened the csv file with textEdit and saw this:

[image]

I think the problem is how to tell the compiler when to break off a new line. For example, right now, it will read z (row 2) as being on the previous row. Please take a look at my code and output below (i am using Xcode v 9.2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ip("ebid2016.csv");
    if (!ip.is_open()) {
        cout << "can't open file" << '\n';
    }
    string title;
    string articleId;
    string department;
    string closeDate;
    string bid;
    string inventoryId;
    string vehicleId;
    string receiptNum;
    string fund;
    string nothing;


    while(ip.good()){

        getline(ip,title,'\t');
        getline(ip,articleId,'\t');
        getline(ip,department,'\t');
        getline(ip,closeDate,'\t');
        getline(ip,bid,'\t');
        getline(ip,inventoryId,'\t');
        getline(ip,vehicleId,'\t');
        getline(ip,receiptNum,'\t');
        getline(ip,fund,'\t');

        cout << "Article Title:" << title << '\n';
        cout << "Article ID:" << articleId << '\n';
        cout << "Department:" << department << '\n';
        cout << "Close Date:" << closeDate << '\n';
        cout << "Bid:" << bid << '\n';
        cout << "Inventory ID:" << inventoryId << '\n';
        cout << "Vehicle ID:" << vehicleId << '\n';
        cout << "Receipt Number:" << receiptNum << '\n';
        cout << "Fund:" << fund << '\n';

        cout << "------------------" << '\n';
    }
    ip.close();
}
```

Output:

```
Article Title:ArticleTitle
Article ID:ArticleID
Department:Department 
Close Date:CloseDate 
Bid:WinningBid 
Inventory ID:InventoryID
Vehicle ID:VehicleID
Receipt Number:ReceiptNumber 
Fund:Fund
z <------------why does z show up here?
------------------
Article Title:97991
Article ID:POLICE PROPERTY AND EVIDENCE UNCLAIMED
Department:12/1/16
Close Date:$27.00 
Bid:PPEU-031C-149
Inventory ID:
Vehicle ID:3689905552
Receipt Number:Enterprise
Table
Fund:97990
------------------ etc.
```

Comment: The last field ends with `\n` not `\t`.

Comment: Apart from anything else, that data file is not CSV.

Comment: Perhaps: `getline(ip,fund,'\t');` --> `getline(ip,fund,'\n');`

Comment: This is not a duplicate; OP is not writing a CSV parser; instead they are writing a custom text file parser for this particular format.

Comment: Also, for why not to use `while(ip.good()){` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Indeed @NeilButterworth it appears to be tab delimited.  Maybe it's appropriate to edit the question title?

Comment: Not sure we want to go down the road of suggesting random things that could be done to improve this project.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fix is:

`getline(ip,fund,'\n');`

You are reading the Fund field until it reaches the next tab character (\t), when in actuality you want to read to the next newline.

Comment: Thanks. Your approach worked for the first row, but the rest of the rows lost all their formatting and were printed as is: eg `z,97991,POLICE PROPERTY AND EVIDENCE UNCLAIMED,12/1/16,$27.00 ,PPEU-031C-149,,3689905552,Enterprise`

Comment: Sounds like a new problem and a new question.  Considering the downvotes, I suggest you try a new question and don't say you want to "parse CSV" since you are parsing a tab delimited text file in a specifically formatted way.